# Getting error on my GET request even though I didn't call the GET request

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

So when an element is clicked I trigger this ajax GET function:

```
$('a.username').on('click', function() {

    var username = $(this).html();
    var url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        data: {
            username_clicked: username,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.username_clicked)
        }
    })
});
```

which gets the text of the element clicked (aka the username). This successfully sends to my **view** which captures the GET data through the following code:

```
username_clicked = request.GET.get('username_clicked')
print(username_clicked) #prints the correct text
```

However when I add this code under the above text in the view:

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(username=username_clicked)
if username_clicked:
    print(profile.age)
```

It gives me this error ONLOAD:

```
DoesNotExist at /news/151/
    Profile matching query does not exist.
```

How can this error be raised if I haven't even triggered the click() event? The error appears when I load the page. Also just to reassure, when I manually add an instance of username, e.g. like this: `profile = Profile.objects.get(username='zorgan')`, that works fine. But it won't take a variable for some reason.

Here's my **models** if you're wondering:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='AnonymousUser')
    age = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Any idea?

**Full view**:

```
def article(request, category, id):

    name = resolve(request.path).kwargs['category']
    for a, b in CATEGORY_CHOICES:
        if b == name:
            name = a
            instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id, category=name)

    allauth_login = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    allauth_signup = SignupForm(request.POST or None)

    #comments
    comment = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    ajax_comment = request.POST.get('text')
    comment_length = len(str(ajax_comment))

    comment_list = Comment.objects.filter(destination=id)
    score = CommentScore.objects.filter(comment=comment_list)

    if request.is_ajax():
        if comment.is_valid():
            comment = Comment.objects.create(comment_text=ajax_comment, author=str(request.user), destination=id)
            comment.save()

            score = CommentScore.objects.create(comment=comment)
            score.save()
            username = str(request.user)
            return JsonResponse({'text': ajax_comment, 'text_length': comment_length, 'username': username})
        else:
            print(comment.errors)


    username_clicked = request.GET.get('username_clicked')
    print(username_clicked)
    profile = Profile.objects.get(username=username_clicked)
    if username_clicked:
        print(profile.age)


    context = {
        'score': score,
        'comment_list': comment_list,
        'comment': comment,
        'instance': instance,
        'allauth_login': allauth_login,
        'allauth_signup': allauth_signup
    }

    return render(request, 'article.html', context)
```

Comment: Please show the whole view. But the initial load *is* a GET request, so I don't understand why you say you didn't call it.

Comment: You should query this profile = Profile.objects.get(username=username_clicked) after the if username_clicked: condition

Comment: Or put it in inside the `is_ajax()` block.

Comment: Putting it inside the `is_ajax()` makes it work, thankyou Daniel.

Comment: @DanielRoseman This works but it ruins my other ajax call (the `comment` one) as it returns the same ` Profile matching query does not exist` error when I make an ajax comment. Do you have a better solution?